# Remove n number of characters in a string after a specific character

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to remove citation numbers from a string in the following way using R:

Original string:

```
"There were 100 people outside.231 They were sharing 10 hotdogs.42 Nice!"
```

Desired string:

```
"There were 100 people outside. They were sharing 10 hotdogs. Nice!"
```

but I'm admittedly very bad with Regex. Would anyone possibly have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So the idea is te remove the numbers after a period?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes! But only those which are following a period without a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `(?<=\\.)\\d+` to match the digits after a period, e.g.,

```
> gsub("(?<=\\.)\\d+", "", s, perl = TRUE)
[1] "There were 100 people outside. They were sharing 10 hotdogs. Nice!"
```

---

A more efficient way (thank @JvdV's comment) might be

```
gsub("\\.\\d+", ".", s, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think the lookbehind is creating a bit too much overhead than needed. Maybe just `gsub("\\.\\d+", ".", s, perl = TRUE)`? Where this would only take a few steps (7), the lookbehind takes [100+](https://regex101.com/r/GnYADL/2).

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for the suggestion, I added yours into the answer

Answer (score 1):

To remove a number after a period (you could make this more elaborate for any edge cases you might have) you can find a word, a period and then group capture the integers. Replace those integers with an empty string.

What I do here is I find two groups. First group is a word with a period and the second group are integers that follow it. I return just the word (first group denoted by `\\1`), discarding the integers.

```
> gsub("(\\w\\.)(\\d+)", replacement = "\\1", x = xy, perl = TRUE)
[1] "There were 100 people outside. They were eating hotdogs. Nice!"
```