# How to trim a long string after several colons to n characters?

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to do this with **gsub** and/or **dplyr** in R:

Ok here's the example text:

```
example_string <-
  "Bing Bloop Doop:-14490 Flerp:01 ScoobyDoot:Z1Bling Blong:Zootsuitssasdfasdf"
```

What I'd like to get:

```
"Bing Bloop Doop: Flerp: ScoobyDoot:Z1Bling Blong:Zootsuit"
```

I'd like to strip all the numbers (and any hyphens) except for the Z# and then limit the nchar after the last colon to 9 char. There are always 4 colons.

I'm going through all different kinds of threads and they get close sometimes but no cigar.

I was able to remove all digits:

gsub('[0-9]+', '', example_string)

But this doesn't trim nchar to 9 at the end and also takes out the Z1 part:

```
"Bing Bloop Doop: Flerp: ScoobyDoot:ZBling Blong:Zootsuitssasdfasdf"
```

[Remove n number of characters in a string after a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753395/remove-n-number-of-characters-in-a-string-after-a-specific-character)

[Regex allow a string to only contain numbers 0 - 9 and limit length to 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968049/regex-allow-a-string-to-only-contain-numbers-0-9-and-limit-length-to-45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using a combination of base R functions (strsplit, lapply and gsub). Splitting the strings using the colon, and then iterate over each split element to re-split them using a space, detecting a combination of digits (positive/negative) and then re-collapsing using the space and the colon.

```
# Split the string by the colon
colon_split <- unlist(strsplit(example_string, ":"))

# Over all strings split by the colon
digits_out <- lapply(colon_split, \(x) {
  space <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s"))
  gsub("^-(\\d*)$|^(\\d*)$", "", space) |> paste0(collapse = " ")
})

# Regroup and collapse using the colon  
paste0(digits_out, collapse = ":")
```

Comment: That works thank you! Can you help me understand the regex in gsub? like I dont understand the $, |, and ^ parts

Comment: Sure! The `^` is indicating the start of the string. `\\d` is any single digit, and `*` is zero or more of what preceeds. `|` is just 'or'. `$` is the end of the string. In words, `gsub("^-(\\d*)$|^(\\d*)$", "", space)` means:
Replace by nothing a string that starts by `-` then followed by and only by any amount of single digits, until the end of the string. OR, replace by nothing a string that starts by any amount of single digits, until the end of the string.
I suggest you go read on regular expressions. Here is a great website for testing them: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR solution:

If you expect your conditions to remain the same, this solution doesn't require iterating through the different colon strings, using gsub only once.

```
example_string <- 
    "Bing Bloop Doop:-14490 Flerp:01 ScoobyDoot:Z1Bling Blong:Zootsuitssasdfasdf"

# use gsub to replace with ""
re_pattern <- "(?<!Z)[0-9]|-"
res <- gsub(re_pattern, "", example_string,perl=T) # perl allows use of complex regex patterns

# split up by colon
colon_splits = unlist(strsplit(res, ":"))

# get substring of last (5th) colon string 
last_colon_str = substring(colon_splits[5],0,8) # (chars 0-8 since result wanted was "Zootsuit")

str_list = c(colon_splits[0:4],last_colon_str) # collapse using c()

# regroup and collapse (thanks bdbmax)
paste0(str_list, collapse=":")
```

## Regex Explanation

Each `|` is an OR conditional separator. You can usually use it when there's multiple patterns to match.

### That being said, there are 2 "groups" of patterns here:

#### 1. Z# and numbers `"(?<!Z)[0-9]"`

We can further break down `(?<!Z)[0-9]` to:

```
"(?<!Z)" # a negative lookbehind
"[0-9]" # a group that captures a range of 0 to 9
```

this allows you to match numbers 0 to 9 (`[0-9]`, see 2 for explanation) that are not preceded by a 'Z' (`(?<!Z)`).

For more info you can take a look at [this explanation of lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

#### 2. hyphen `-`

the hyphen that you want to remove. If you would like to include more characters, you can do:

```
"[-$]"
```

bear in mind that if you include other characters, in order to prevent the `-` from being interpreted as a range, you need to use [escape characters](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#All-the-sequences-and-escapes):

```
"[1\-2]" # matches "1", "2", and "-"
```